# Vista Style Builder - Startmenu Bug, Resizing the Taskbar

Tags: themes

I'm not sure how many people who use Vista Style Builder are on here, but I have three questions:

1. <strike>How can I edit this bit of the start menu (outlined in red)? I'm modifying a theme, and I can't for the life of me figure out why it's green in stead of blue.

   http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12147973/vista-style-builder-help.png</strike>
2. For the search bar on the start menu, how do I add a margin or something to the bottom so it's not smack against the taskbar? I'm very new at style building, so please excuse my n00b questions.
3. How can I make the taskbar 1px (or ideally 0px) high? I use a taskbar hider to hide it normally, but the start menu still shows up 44px above the bottom of the screen. I tried setting everything to 0 in the start menu's margin areas, but it only got a little smaller.

EDIT: The green is showing up in the jumplist highlights as well, so it's not just a start menu thing.

EDIT 2: This solved #1 - (copy/paste not working will put in link later)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the visastylebuilder forums insetad or contact a visualstyle designer at deviantart...
*the change for a reply is mostly zero here...

Comment: I figured, but I thought I'd give it a shot. Thanks.